# Get all post from table and put it in excel sheet

Tags: export

I have website with 25025 posts, And i need to get the post name and the post url for all post in 2014. and export it in Excel sheet.

How can i do that.

i try to do this query but i dont get the URL of post and get all post in 2014

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";
```

Comment: I guess you can drop `post_date < NOW()` as those posts shouldn't have a post status of `publish`, as they are scheduled. Also: Why do you compare the `posts.ID` with the `postmeta.post_id`?

Comment: Another problem might be that the Excel specification is as of now a 41MB PDF download. I hope you understand that the exact specifications are out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the SQL I used to create this view in phpMyAdmin. Since you cannot get the permalink URL out of the database we have to pull the GUID. This link does in fact get you to your post, since it uses the unique ID of the post.

```
SELECT `post_name`, `guid`
FROM `YOUR_TABLE` 
WHERE `post_date` >= DATE('2014-01-01')
ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
```

For all of the data in your posts table use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `YOUR_TABLE` 
WHERE `post_date` >= DATE('2014-01-01')
ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
```

Comment: Why did you only select the `post_name` and the `guid` columns?

Comment: He asked for post name and the URL. Since the database doesn't store the full URL, that's what we can get out. But I'd agree some of the other information is useful, that's not what OP asked for. I've updated the answer to include the `select *`

Comment: The GUID is **absolutely no source for permalinks**. You can't do it that way. The GUID is the _GLOBALS UNIQUE ID_ and nothing else. WordPress just happens to make it look like a permalink.

Comment: Right. WP_Rewrite forces the permalinks. You can't get the permalink URL out of the database. It's based on the post_name, category_base, etc. But you CAN go to the GUID url and get the post.

Comment: Seems someone already jumped in and downvoted it. Upvoted after your addition, but you might want to add the permalink story and the comments discussion conclusions as well. Not everyone reads comments :)

Comment: Hopefully that's better and will get the OP to their destination. Thanks for the insight and making the answer better.